# How to use generic in TypeScript properly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing component where I need to use generics. But I have some problems with that.

My component has to get different data from server. Thus I need to use generics.

Me test component looks so:

App component:

```
interface ITodos {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  checked: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
}

const App = () => 
return (
      <TableTest<ITodos>
        columns={todos}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

```
export interface IData<T> {
  id: number,
}

export interface ITable<T> {
  columns: IData<T>[],
}
export default function TableTest<T>(props:ITable<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.columns.map((todo) => <div>{todo.title}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Am I on the right way? But I get mistake "Property 'title' does not exist". I understand why TypeScript gives such a mistake, because there is no field in type IData.

How to fix that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you add the `title` prop to `IData` then?

Comment: Thats why I ask a piece of advice. 
Props can be always different and I want to make my component reusable. 
I mean my component can get in props todolist, users or something like that.

Comment: But if you *need* to use the `title` prop, then it *has* to be in the constraint? I'm not sure what the problem is; if you don't want to add it to the interface, then you shouldn't use it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always show the same field in the table you should inherit from a main class like this

```
import "./styles.css";

interface Base {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface ITodos extends Base {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  checked: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
}

interface ITable<T> {
  columns: T[];
}

function TableTest<T extends Base>(props: ITable<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.columns.map((todo) => (
        <div>{todo.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const todos = Array.from(Array(10), (a, i) => ({
    id: i,
    title: `Todo ${i}`,
    body: `Todo Body ${i}`,
    checked: false,
    disabled: false
  }));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TableTest<ITodos> columns={todos} />
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to change the field you want to show you can try this

```
import "./styles.css";

type DynamicObjectType = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

interface TableProps {
  columns: DynamicObjectType[];
  field: string;
}

function TableTest(props: TableProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.columns.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo[props.field]}>{todo[props.field]}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const todos = Array.from(Array(10), (a, i) => ({
    id: i,
    title: `Todo ${i}`,
    body: `Todo Body ${i}`,
    checked: false,
    disabled: false
  }));
  const todos2 = Array.from(Array(10), (a, i) => ({
    id: i,
    title2: `Todo2 ${i}`
  }));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TableTest columns={todos} field={"title"} />
      <hr />
      <TableTest columns={todos2} field={"title2"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```